# C++ stringstream string to function(test, char *test2)

Tags: c++, string, parameters, char

Have a MySQL query function, that needs to take a string parameter.
Which looks like this:

```
cin >> user_string;
stringstream ss;
ss << "select * from " << user_string;
```

Function looks like this:

```
mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *connection, char *sql_query)
```

Tried to convert to ss.c_str(); or ss.str().c_str();
Does not work.

What would be the correct way to do this? Skip Stingstream and build char?
C++ Strings confuses me...

Comment: "Tried to convert to ss.c_str(); or ss.str().c_str(); Does not work." - care to expand as to how this "doesn't work".

Comment: The problem is that the `mysql` takes a non-const `char*`, and the `stringstream` will give you a `const char*` handle to its internal data...

Comment: Honestly, that should be closed as a 101 duplicate.

Comment: mysql_workbench.cpp:100: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’
mysql_workbench.cpp:100: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘MYSQL_RES* mysql_perform_query(MYSQL*, char*)’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unusual that `mysql_perform_query` doesn't want a `const char *`.

If that's your code, change it to accept a `const char *` and your approach will work.

```
mysql_perform_query( connection, user_string.str().c_str() );
```

If you can't change that function signature, this will work*.

```
mysql_perform_query( connection, &user_string.str()[0] );
```

**It's guaranteed to work in C++11, and while not guaranteed in C++03, does work in all common implementations*

Comment: @idontgetdottynetty You don't say which of his suggestions worked.  The last one may work with some implementations, or some of the time, but you cannot be sure (and the `&` operator in the first shouldn't be there either).

Comment: The last still won't work on some implementation (or some of the time).  There is no reason to assume that `&user_string.str()[0]` is `'\0'` terminated.

Comment: mysql_perform_query(connection, &ss.str()[0]));  worked just fine.

Comment: @idontgetdottynetty For simple test cases, probably.  In a large, complex program, where there have been a lot of allocations and frees previously, it depends on the implementation.  (I believe that MSVC does make it work, at least in their current version.  But I don't think that this is official, and I wouldn't count on it.)

Comment: Ok, well just have to see if i encounter bugs later on in this little program, hopefully not. Still have a couple of years to go before i can start making large complex programs hehe:)

Comment: @JamesKanze It took me a while, but [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) states that since C++11, the internal "one past the end" char must be `char()` (a null-terminator)

Comment: @DrewDormann Where does it state that?  I found that if the
string has length `n`, the characters in the half-open range
`[0...n)` must be contiguous (§21.4.1/5), and that `s[n]` must
return a reference to an object of type `T` with value
`charT()` (§21.4.5/2), but the text _in_ §21.4.5/2 takes pains
to make it clear that this `s[n]` is _not_ part of the internal
representation.

Comment: @JamesKanze in your opinion, do you think I should delete this answer?

Comment: @DrewDormann Or fix it.  It's sufficient to do append a `'\0'` manually to the string at some point.  You could even use `&(user_string.str() + '\0')[0]`  (although this may be pushing what you'd want in a single expression for some people).

Comment: @DrewDormann Of course, if the called function doesn't actually modify the string, then a `const_cast` on `user_string.str().c_str()` is even simpler, and if it does, you probably don't want to use a temporary, because you want to be able to use the results.

Comment: @JamesKanze I can not delete an accepted answer, it seems.  You are welcome to edit it to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

`ss.str().c_str()` is a `const char *` not a `char *` that is required. I would copy `ss.str().c_str()` into a `char *` then pass it to the function.

Comment: Ok, for some reason i cant call ss.c_str() directly have to do this -> ss.str().c_str()

Answer (score 1):

`ss.str().c_str()` would be correct if only your function was

```
mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *connection, const char *sql_query);
```

This is because `c_str()` returns `const char *`.

If you are able to change the `mysql_perform_query` function to `const char *` then I would do so. Otherwise you could consider doing a const_cast, `const_cast<char*>(ss.str().c_str())`.

In the unlikely event that mysql_perform_query really does modify the C string being passed to it then you will have to copy your string to a vector and pass a pointer to that instead.

```
string str = ss.str();
vector<char> tmp(str.begin(), str.end());
tmp.push_back('\0');
mysql_perform_query(connection, &tmp[0]);
```

Comment: Don't forget the `'\0'` terminator in the vector.  (Also, you can probably use `&str[0]` directly.  As long as you ensure that there is a trailing `'\0'` there too.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, Oops I'll fix that.

Comment: The worst thing about that type of bug is that the code will often work in a quick test (where you're the first person to use the memory, and the system has cleared it all before giving it to you, just in case the previous user had left a password lying around).

Answer (score 1):

The SQL interface probably requires a `char const*`.  `ss.str()`
will give you a string, and `ss.str().c_str()` will give you
a `char const*` from that string.

To points, however (more style than anything):

- unless you actually need the bidirectional capacities of
  `stringstream`, it's probably preferable to use the simpler
  `ostringstream` (which only does output), and
- if all you're doing is concatenation, there's no point in
  using streams at all, just use the `+` operator on the strings.
  (You can also use `+` to concatenate a string and a string
  literal.)  Streams are really for formatting and parsing, and
  are overkill (unnecessary added complexity) for simple
  concatenation.

Comment: Okey, good point! New to this language. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score -2):

stringstream has a str method that returns a std::string; std::string has a c_str() method that returns a pointer to a char.

```
mysql_perform_query(connection, ss.str().c_str());
```

You did do a proper search before posting your question, didn't you?

Comment: Yep, const char * to char * function() apparently :)